# Cadeia de caracteres não foi reconhecida como DateTime válido

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

```
protected void ButtonPesquisar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var _macro = new LFSistemas.VLI.ACTWeb.Entities.Macro();

    var macroController = new MacroController();
    var itens = macroController.ObterTodos(new Entities.FiltroMacro()
    {
    //DataInicio = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBoxDataInicio.Text + "" + TextBoxHoraInicio.Text),
    //DataFim = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBoxHoraFim.Text + "" + TextBoxHoraFim.Text),
    DataInicio = new DateTime(2013, 08, 12, 20, 10, 00),
    //DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10)
        DataFim = new DateTime(2013, 08, 12, 20, 30, 00)
    });
```

Hoje meu código está rodando desta maneira, porém estou querendo pesquisar meus dados através das informações informadas no textBox.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-2 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
        <label for="data_inicio">Data Inicio</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDataInicio" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-2 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
        <label for="hora_inicio">Hora Inicio</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxHoraInicio" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-2 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
        <label for="data_fim">Data Fim</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDataFim" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-2 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
        <label for="hora_fim">Hora Fim</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxHoraFim" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-align-right">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" class="btn btn-link pro-btn inline-button ajustar-lg" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">Limpar</asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonPesquisar" CssClass="btn btn-primary pro-btn inline-button ajustar-lg" runat="server" Text="Pesquisar" OnClick="ButtonPesquisar_Click" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Tentei implementar da maneira que está comentanda porém está dando o erro: Cadeia de caracteres não foi reconhecida como DateTime válido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

olha fiz um teste e rodou de boa, notei que faltou o espaço na sua concatenação!

olha só: http://prntscr.com/4pbep5

o cód:

```
 protected void Unnamed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    DateTime dataa;
    DateTime.TryParse(data.Text + " " + hora.Text, out dataa);

    Response.Write(dataa.ToString("hh:mm:ss - dd/MM/yyyy"));
 }
```

E na parte do aspx:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="hora" placeholder="hora"/>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="data" placeholder="data"/>
    <br />
    <asp:Button Text="e vai!" runat="server" OnClick="Unnamed_Click"/>
</div>
</form>
```

**UDPATE 001**

Saquei deve ser por causa do `out`, tenta isso:

`var itens = macroController.ObterTodos(new Entities.FiltroMacro()
{
   DataInicio = DateTime.Parse(TextBoxDataInicio.Text + " " + TextBoxHoraInicio.Text),
   DataFim = DateTime.Parse(TextBoxHoraFim.Text + " " + TextBoxHoraFim.Text)
});`

Tome bastante cuidado com as Cultures, a Ui e a Info. Caso não consiga poste aí um comentário na minha resposta, se te ajudar de um +1 e se resolver teu problema marque-a como correta! Valeuu!

Comment: Não conseguir pegar a ideia do seu exemplo e implementar em meu código.

Comment: Faça assim: `DateTime dataa; DateTime.TryParse(TextBoxDataInicio.Text + " " + TextBoxHoraInicio.Text, out dataa);`, ao executar os valores serão concatenados e jogados para a variavel `dataa`.

Comment: No seu exemplo roda legal, agora no meu código que está osso de implementar.

Comment: dá uma olhada ali... :D

Comment: No código passou beleza, porém quando clico no botão pesquisar da minha tela exibe o erro da pergunta. Teria mais alguma sugestão do que eu possa fazer? Ou quer que edite minha pergunta com mais informações

Comment: Cara, acho que no meu exemplo faltou mais um espaço que acabei esquecendo de colocar. Testa mais uma vez por favor!

Comment: Então, implementei o código e não apresenta mais o erro. Porém não está filtrando pelo filtro informado nos textBox.

Comment: Deu certo agora, tinha um negocio errado na minha propriedade ItemTemplate. Valeu demais !!!

Answer (score 1):

`Convert.ToDateTime()` não dá opções de formato de data.

Utilize [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx):

```
CultureInfo cultura = new CultureInfo("pt-BR"); 
DateTime minhaData;
DateTime.TryParseExact(TextBoxDataInicio.Text + " " + TextBoxHoraInicio.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm", cultura, DateTimeStyles.None, out minhaData);
```

`minhaData` receberá o valor se as informações forem válidas.